# Symbol export and Meteor local package

Tags: meteor, package, meteor-accounts

I'd like to build a custom authentification procedure for a Meteor app. 
To that end, I have created a local package into the `myApp/packages` folder with the following command:

```
meteor create --package accounts-custom
```

As a simple test, I have cloned [accounts-password package code](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/packages/accounts-password) there and added the local package to my app:

```
meteor add accounts-custom
```

Il would expect this setup to be equivalent of directly adding `accounts-password` to the app (`meteor add accounts-password`)

But running the app gives me an error:

```
Accounts.findUserByEmail is not a function
```

`findUserByEmail` is defined by `accounts-password`... which makes me think that my custom package is not correctly taken into account...
How can I redefine `Accounts` from a local package? Any insight?

Answer (score 1):

In case this could help anyone, it finally worked adding `api.mainModule('server-main.js', 'server')` in the `package.js` file